# Changing button background color on mouse-over event

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, background-color, onmouseover

I am developing a project in C# Windows applications (WinForms) in that I need to create a function to change the background color for all the buttons that are in the single form using button mouse-over event.  How do I do that?

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF? And what is "lidos"?

Comment: You're going to need to explain the problem a bit more. Are the buttons changing just in your app? Or are you changing another app's buttons?

Comment: myself clearly mention in the question that is windows application if that is Wpf controls means i need to write Wpf controls

Comment: lol, yeah, you do now after editing your question, while the comments where before

Comment: My first posting is also like that only

Comment: @Lawrance - Winforms and WPF are not the same...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing all controls of type Button:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Controls.Count; i++)
            if (Controls[i] is Button) Controls[i].BackColor = Color.Blue;
```

Example of hooks:

```
MouseEnter += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetButtonColour(Color.Blue);
    });

MouseLeave += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetButtonColour(Color.Red);
    });

public void SetButtonColour(Color colour)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Controls.Count; i++)
            if (Controls[i] is Button) Controls[i].BackColor = Color.Blue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are just changing your own app, this isn't that difficult.

In the mouse over event, just loop over the Controls property of the form and for all items that are Button, change the back color.  You will need to write a recursive function to find all of the buttons probably though, since a Panel (or GroupBox, etc) contains a Controls property for all of its controls.

Comment: like that only am doing, all the buttons are placed inside the groupbox, i already tryed that for textbox as below code, but changing backcolor using mouse over event is somewhat critical to me  

public static void Fungbstyle(GroupBox gbsty){
gbsty.BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
gbsty.Cursor = Cursors.AppStarting;
foreach (Control cnn in gbsty.Controls){
if (cnn is TextBox){
cnn.BackColor = Color.LightCyan;
cnn.Cursor = Cursors.PanNW;
cnn.Font = new Font(cnn.Font, FontStyle.Italic);
cnn.Width = 156;
}}}

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Color defaultColor;
    Color hoverColor = Color.Orange;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        defaultColor = button1.BackColor;
    }

    private void Form1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is Button)
            {
                ctrl.BackColor = hoverColor;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is Button)
            {
                ctrl.BackColor = defaultColor;
            }
        }
    }
}
```